# Complete shutting down of Android app when any form of exiting is done i.e. using HOME, SWITCH and BACK button

Tags: android

I'm building an Android app specifically a log in page whereby I'd like the app to completely shut down the app if the user was to exit the log in page in any way i.e. using the SWITCH, HOME or BACK buttons.

The only time the app should not completely shut down should be when user successfully logs in i.e. when the custom created log in button or enter button is pressed.

I've been able to do successfully shut down the app but in shuts down even when the user successfully logs. It isn't meant to do this.

Below is my code for the complete shut down - I took over the onDestroy(), onBackPressed(), finish() and onStop() methods:

```
    // Deal with back button
public void onBackPressed() {
    System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);

    System.exit(0);     
}

// Deal with exiting of app
public void finish() {

    System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);

    System.exit(0);

}

// Deal with exiting of app
public void onDestroy() {
    System.runFinalizersOnExit(true); 

    System.exit(0);
}

// Deal with exiting of app
public void onStop() {
    System.runFinalizersOnExit(true); 

    System.exit(0);
}
```

DOES ANYONE HAVE ANY IDEAS REGARDING MY ISSUE

YOUR ASSISTANCE IS GREATLY APPRECIATED

Comment: You don't have `@Override` on any of those or `super.onStop()` or any other `super.method()`. Could that cause an issue?

Comment: @TronicZomB `@Override` annotation is only a convenience which helps if an overriden method is somehow renamed or removed, as it will causes compiler warning/error. It is not mandatory at all

Comment: @nicopico OK thanks. I am still learning so that is great to know.

Comment: @TronicZomB: Hi and thanks, having super.onStop(); at the start of the onStop() doesn't prevent it from completely exiting when the user successfully signs in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a class member boolean `mLoggedIn` and set it to **true** when the custom created log in button or enter button is pressed.
Then

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (!mLoggedIn) 
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29) for an explanation of the `onStop()` method. I suppose you open another `Activity` when the user has successfully logged in, your `Activity` above becomes invisible and calls `onStop()` where you exit your app. So just don't override `onStop()`.

Comment: Hi and thanks. Indeed I call another activity i.e. the home page when the user logs in. I've stopped overriding the onStop() but my issue still exists i.e. assuming the user exits the app either using the home button or switch button the app does not completely shut down and I require it to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The `onStop()` method is called each time your activity is made invisible: when your app goes to the background, when the screen is turned off, or **when you switch to another activity**.

Regardless, what you are trying to do is **strongly discouraged**.
See this [forum thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Zhd1fRfHAAQ) (Dianne Hackborn being one of the lead developer of the Android Framework).

Force closing your app using `System.exit()`, `Process.killProcess()` and the likes has a strong risk of conflict with the Android application lifecycle, and can corrupt its saved state, leading to unexpected and unpleasant behaviors for your users.

A better way is to use the flags [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) and [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) when launching your login activity. 
This should remove previous activities from application, which would be the same as starting a new application from a user point of view.

Comment: @nicopio: Hi and thanks. I've read the forum and I understand calling onStop() is discouraged, any ideas on how I could fully shut down app from if the user was to exit usin the home and switch buttons or to exit the app say through picking a call? Thanks

Comment: @AMonari I made an edit to my post which could get you some leads on a proper way to achieve what you want. And you can **override** `onStop()`, it is the call to `System.exit()` which is discouraged.